# Can a ros node do the equivalent of 'rosnode ping'

Tags: rosnode, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way (hopefully in rospy) do something like 'rosnode ping' natively? I want to check if another node is running.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29205/can-a-ros-node-do-the-equivalent-of-%27rosnode-ping%27/) by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1033 on 2012-03-06

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, but its probably a bad idea to code this sort of logic into your nodes.  The intent of an anon pub/sub system is to not know what other nodes are running.  That way you can freely interchange bags, alternate implementations, etc... Instead, test for the data/state you want to see, rather than the nodes you want to see.

For how to do the ping operation, simply read the source of rosnode.  It requires making outbound XMLRPC calls, so it is a 'slow' operation.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2012-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) on 2012-03-07**:
Thanks for the answer. Yeah, this is not a good idea generally, but it makes sense for my project.

**Comment by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) on 2012-03-07**:
As a follow-up, can a node figure out it's actual name? (If it was created with anonymous=True).

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2012-03-07**:
Please see the API overview docs: http://ros.org/wiki/rospy/Overview/Names%20and%20Node%20Information